# Cannot login through Firefox in AskUbuntu

Tags: firefox, login, websites

When I try to login to AskUbuntu through the latest (29.0) Firefox, it won't let me.

I press the login button, and without pressing "Login with Google" or anything else, I see a popup saying:

"Welcome back hakermania, you've been logged in.
You are being redirected..."

but then it just redirects me to the main AskUbuntu page and it does not show me logged in.

This appears to happen only in AskUbuntu. Other StackExchange sites like StackOverflow seem to work pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Edit` Menu -> `Preference` -> `Privacy` Tab -> Click on `Firefox will:` & select `Use custom settings for history` -> click `Show Cookies` -> `Delete All Cookies`

OR ELSE

Go to `Help` Menu -> `Troubleshooting Information` -> Click `Reset Information`.

This will make your firefox to default settings.